# How to use another field as value instead of "Id" in ajax mode Select2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I need to submit the text name as value if id is equal to zero.
For example select2 ajax result is:

```
{
   id:1,
   name:"abc"
},
{
   id:2,
   name:"xyz"
},{
   id:0,
   name:"pqr"
},{
   id:0,
   name:"ijk"
}
```

Now, if 'abc' option get selected then i need value 1.. but if 'pqr' or 'ijk' option get selected , both have same id 0 i want text as value. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can set name and id with same value e.g.

```js
{
   id:"abc",
   name:"abc"
},
{
   id:"xyz",
   name:"xyz"
},
{
   id:"pqr",
   name:"pqr"
},
{
   id:"ijk",
   name:"ijk"
}
```

Comment: but i need original id's for those who have id not 0

Comment: Then value should be unique for particular option selection.